# The Symfony Kernel does not find namespace from Symlinked composer packages

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony5

I am currently working on a reusable user management bundle.
Everything works fine by registering this bundle locally in composer.json.

Unfortunately, once out of the project, and loaded with "path > symlink" in composer nothing works anymore.

> Attempted to load class "DcognataUserBundle" from namespace "Dcognata\UserBundle".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

```
#sf-project/composer.json

"require": {
    ...
    "dcognata/user-bundle": "1.0",
    ...
},

...

"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../UserBundle",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    }
]
```

```
#package/composer.json

{
    "name": "dcognata/user-bundle",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "description": "Symfony DcUserBundle",
    "homepage": "~",
    "keywords": [
        "User management"
    ],
    "version": "1.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "~",
            "email": "~"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Dcognata\\UserBundle\\": ""
        }
    },
    "support": {
        "docs": "~"
    }
}
```

The package is correctly installed in the vendor/ folder.
[Package correct installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dlXA.png)

Do you have a lead to help me fix this problem?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT :**

```
 ---------------------------- ------------------------ 
  Bundle name                  Extension alias         
 ---------------------------- ------------------------ 
  DcognataUserBundle           dcognata_user
```

After a few tries, new information

The bundle seems to be properly loaded after all.
The error only occurs in the kernel.

The bundle commands are functional. The error occurs only on the front end.

---

**Finally**

I've finally changed my ways. My Bundle will be loaded from github and not locally by the time it's uploaded to packagist....

It seems to work!

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:username/user-bundle.git"
    }
]
```